# How to send parameter in AJAX (rest-api) using django?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I utilities rest-api in django,
and I don't succeed to send a "GET" parameter through ajax:

In rest-api app in django I have in the urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^titles/(?P<author_id>\d+)/$', login_required(views.TitlesViewSet.as_view()) ),
)
```

In views.py I wrote:

```
class TitlesViewSetViewSet(ListCreateAPIView):
     serializer_class = TitleSerializer

     def get_queryset(self):
         aouther_id = self.request.GET.get('aouther_id', None)
         return Title.objects.filter(auther = auther_id)
```

when the code insert to the get_queryset above it doesn't recognize any GET parameter and the aouther_id is set to None.

Does anybody know what I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have a typo in urls, you are using `author_id` and in view you are trying to get the `aouther_id` key. Second, you are trying to get the value from the query parameters, but you are not actually using them. Third, you are using named url parameters and those are being stored in the `kwargs` property of your class based view.

You can access them this way:

```
class TitlesViewSetViewSet(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TitleSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        # try printing self.kwargs here, to see the contents
        return Title.objects.filter(author_id=self.kwargs.get('author_id'))
```

Answer (score 1):

you should replace a line of the auther_id setting to:

```
auther_id=self.kwargs['auther_id']
```

update:
I now see jbub answer... thanks man! I just discovered it...